# How to create a TypeScript module containing React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have React application created with `create-react-app` using unejected `react-scripts`.  When I import the module into my React application, I get the following warning:

```
./node_modules/@myscope/webcomponents/dist/components/Mock.d.ts 2:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React, { CSSProperties } from "react";
> export interface IMockProps {
|     children?: React.ReactNode;
|     color: {
```

I am using `tsc` to compile my JS to TypeScript before importing and I have

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
```

specified in my module's `package.json`.  VS Code does not seem to have any issue using the typings in the modules, but `react-scripts start` seems unable to read my typings, failing on `export` or `declare`.

How can I compile a TypeScript module containing React components/JSX that can be imported by the compiler used by `react-scripts`?  `react-scripts start` has no issue with other TypeScript modules, and I cannot distinguish any difference between my working public TypeScript modules and my failing custom TypeScript modules.

## React app tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

## Module tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It seems like your app is trying to import from a `*.d.ts` file which is not allowed (they should be parsed by TypeScript, but nothing executable can be `require`d from them). How does your import statement look?

Comment: My import statement is normal `import {value} from "@myscope/mymodule";`.  My `main` is also a `.js` file, not a `.d.ts` file.